# Using xcolor list in smartdiagram package

Tags: color, smartdiagram

I would like to use  names from dvipsnames option to create color list in smartdiagram. For example. 1. NavyBlue, 2. Orange, 3. GreenYellow, 4. Purple , 5. cornflowerBlue, 6.SpringGreen and 7. CadetBlue, or BlueViolet

The color list is available under this heading "Following are the xcolor color names available with the dvipsnames option" if you google.

example from smartdiagram packages;

```
\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{border color=none,
set color list={blue!50!cyan,green!60!lime,orange!50!red,red!80!black},
back arrow disabled=true}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Set up,Run,Analyse,Modify~/ Add}
\end{center}
```

Any help on seting the color list?
Thank you

Comment: welcome to the site -- the color list below should meet the requirement -- is there something else to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{mypink1}{rgb}{0.858, 0.188, 0.478}
\definecolor{mypink2}{RGB}{219, 48, 122}
\definecolor{mypink3}{cmyk}{0, 0.7808, 0.4429, 0.1412}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.6}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \smartdiagramset{border color=none,
            set color list={mypink1,mypink2,mypink3,mygray},
            back arrow disabled=true}
        \smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Set up,Run,Analyse,Modify~/ Add}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Alternate arrangement with `\xcolor`**

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{LightRubineRed}{RubineRed!70}
\colorlet{Mycolor1}{green!10!orange!90}
\definecolor{Mycolor2}{HTML}{00F9DE}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \smartdiagramset{border color=none,
            set color list={Apricot,Mycolor1,Mycolor2,RubineRed},
            back arrow disabled=true}
        \smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Set up,Run,Analyse,Modify~/ Add}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Another edit for navyblue**

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \smartdiagramset{border color=none,
            set color list={NavyBlue!50!Black,RoyalPurple!40!Violet!40,NavyBlue,RubineRed},
            back arrow disabled=true}
        \smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Set up,Run,Analyse,Modify~/ Add}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

why not select from the table

[image]

Comment: Helllo js bibra, thank you your reply. So suppose how can I get  Navyblue color. Here I mean which combination of colors produce Navyblue, pure purple?

Comment: please have a look at the edit above -- if the answer met your requirement request to accept and upvote

Comment: ``` \begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{border color=none
              set color list={NavyBlue, Orange, GreenYellow, Purple, SpringGreen, Cornflower Blue, CadetBlue},
               back arrow disabled=true
}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Purpose,  Ideas,  Support,  Assumption Biases, Conclusions, Point of View, Analysis}
\end{center} ```

Comment: above is the code I would like to implement. I didnt manage to make it in code form.

Comment: I would like to get the original color as in the set color. In RGB if you want to get Red, just put other color as  zero value.

Comment: thank you for you help bras.